# Run psql from R on MacOS : sh: psql: command not found

Tags: r, bash, psql

I am trying to run the command line program `psql` via an R script using the function `system()`. I want to do so in order to read a `.sql` file that creates automatically a schema and tables in my database.

This is my command in R, I am on MacOS :

```
system("psql -h localhost -U postgres -d db_name -f path_to_the_file.sql")
```

that returns in the Rstudio's console :

```
sh: psql: command not found
Warning message:
In system("psql") : error in running command
```

However, `psql` commands work perfectly fine in my laptop terminal or in the Rstudio's terminal, but I had to edit my bash profile to make them work. Do I have to do the same with some kind of the "Rstudio bash profile" so I will be able to run `psql` through the script ?

On the other hand, if there is an other way to create tables with a `.sql` file using `RPostgreSQL`, I will be happy to use it ! But I haven't found any...

Thanks a lot for your help !!!

Comment: execute `which psql` to get absolute path and use absolute path when calling  `psql`

Comment: Any idea using RPostgreSQL ?